# add bar in paging in the URL

Tags: permalinks, urls

how do I add a bar in my url paging? I need my paging contains trailing slash
example:
my url is so
site.com/page/02
I want you
site.com/page/02/
how do this redirection?

Answer (score 0):

To enforce a [trailing-slash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417551/5623301) policy you need to set this in your [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
 RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I haven't tested either or these, but google never lies...